# How to move the 3d cursor in blender 2.8

Tags: interface, shortcut, 3d-cursor

This question may have been asked already, but I couldn't find it. So, my question is pretty straight forward. With the new movement controls in blender 2.8, I can no longer move the cursor using left click. How would I move the 3d cursor without having to change the controls, since I rather like the new mouse controls compared to the old ones.

Comment: Shift+RMB should do the trick. When in doubt, try any modifier key (Ctrl-Alt-Shift) and any of the Mouse buttons.

Answer (score 14, accepted):

On a computer: <kbd>Shift</kbd> + <kbd>Right Mouse Click</kbd>

Comment: Perfect answer, thank you very much for the helpful information, but if I may ask, what else could you use blender on apart from a computer? :D